# Can someone please explain how the output was obtained for this function?

Tags: c

```
int main(int i, int j) {  
for (i=4; i>0; i--) {  
    j=i;    
    while (j>=0) {  
        printf("X");  
        j--;  
        }  
    printf("%lf\n", (1.0*(i)) / (j+2));  
    }  
}
```

Output:

```
XXXXX 4.0  
XXXX 3.0  
XXX 2.0  
XX 1.0
```

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: Why does the first line print 5 "X's"? & why is the first number 4.0?

Comment: Maybe it prints 5 "X"s because the while (j>=0) loop starts with j set to 4, and ends when j == -1.

Comment: this is a good chance to learn debugging hacks like adding a printf with all applicable variables into the inner/applicable loop... in this case replacing `printf("X");` with `printf("i is %d, j is %d\n",i,j);` after doing that it becomes quite obvious

Answer (score 1):

The `>=` sign is probably confusing you. The code prints out `X` 5 times in the first row instead of 4 (if that's what you mean) is because once `j = 0`, the loop continues once more.

Basically, the value of `j` after the `while` loop ends is `-1`. Substitute it into your last `printf` and the rest of the output makes sense.

If you change the `>=` to a `>`, the code will produce the correct output.

Comment: Thanks, but how the value 4.0 obtained?

Comment: Since `j = -1` at the end of the loop, `(1.0*(i)) / (j+2) = i / (-1 + 2) = i`.

Answer (score 1):

**why does the first line print 5 "X's"? & why is the first number 4.0?**

Because,

j takes values of j = 4,3,2,1,0. Each time it is printing X hence 5X.

After that loop j becomes -1.

Now `1.0*(4) /(-1+2)` => `(4.0/1)`  => `4.0`

Hence the output is `XXXXX 4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Well, j is set to `i`, so it prints `X` `j+1` times due to the `>= 0` check.  Then divides `i` by `j`,  now -1 + 2. which is now one, to get `i`, which it prints to the screen before a newline begins.

Comment: Okay, but why does the first line print 5 "X's"? & why is the first number 4.0?

Comment: Prints 5 X's because 4,3,2,1,0 are five numbers.  Prints out 4 because i = 4 and is divided by j, which is -1, plus 2 is 1.